# recursive functions in typescript/javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, recursion

I am trying to call the following function recursively.

```
 public  getData(key,value){

   this.htmlString += '<span style="color:cornflowerblue">'+key+' </span>:';

    if(value instanceof Object){
      Object.keys(value).forEach(function (keydata) {
        let obj = value[keydata];
        this.getData(keydata,value[keydata]);

        console.log(key,obj,obj instanceof Object)
      });
    }else{
      this.htmlString += '<span>'+value+'</span>';
    }
    return this.htmlString;
  };
```

when i tried to call teh function it was showing an error " Cannot read property 'getData' of undefined. Is there any wrong in the code or any other way to do this.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`forEach` accepts a callback, which is an anonymous function, and `this` inside anonymous function refers to `window` in non-strict mode or `undefined` in strict mode.

You need to bind context:

```
  Object.keys(value).forEach(function (keydata) {
    let obj = value[keydata];
    this.getData(keydata,value[keydata]);

    console.log(key,obj,obj instanceof Object)
  }.bind(this));
```

or use an arrow function:

```
  Object.keys(value).forEach((keydata) => {
    let obj = value[keydata];
    this.getData(keydata,value[keydata]);

    console.log(key,obj,obj instanceof Object)
  });
```

or simply pass pointer to `this` as a second argument to `forEach`:

```
  Object.keys(value).forEach(function (keydata) {
    let obj = value[keydata];
    this.getData(keydata,value[keydata]);

    console.log(key,obj,obj instanceof Object)
  }, this);
```

Comment: You can also pass a [*thisArg*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.foreach) as a second parameter. *this* isn't "context", it's a parameter of an execution context.

Comment: @RobG, thanks, I didn't know that. That's probably something new. I've edited the answer

Comment: It was introduced with *forEach* in [*ECMAScript ed 5*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.18). ;-)

Comment: @RobG, interesting, I must have missed it. Thanks!